Setting max zoom level of QgsRasterLayer with PyQGIS
I'm using PyQGIS to add QgsRasterLayer layers to my project.
This is how I create the layer:
urlWithParams = "type=xyz&url=http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a%7Bq%7D.jpeg?g=1"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, "Bing maps", "wms")

I can set their max zoom level via the QGIS UI (Properties -> Source -> Max Zoom Level, see attached image), but I'd like to do it programmatically via PyQGIS. I've found that this class has the setMaxZoomLevel method:
https://www.qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorTileBasicRendererStyle.html
but I cannot find how to go from a QgsRasterLayer to its QgsVectorTileBasicRendererStyle.
Has anyone done it?


I analyzed the source of the layer and saw, that the "min/max zoom level" are stored in the DataSourceUrl as the zmin/zmax parameters:
print(iface.activeLayer().source())


type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=18&zmin=1

You can replace the zmin/zmax values (i.e. using regex):
import re

layer = iface.activeLayer()
current_source = layer.source()
print(current_source)

new_zmin = 1
new_zmax = 18

updated_source = re.sub(r'zmin=\d+', f'zmin={new_zmin}', current_source)
updated_source = re.sub(r'zmax=\d+', f'zmax={new_zmax}', updated_source)

layer.setDataSource(updated_source, layer.name(), "wms")

layer.triggerRepaint()


Result:


I've added a screenshot of the max zoom level setting. In this case for an OpenStreetMap layer. The zoom level refers to this scale: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels
The scale solution you proposed didn't work. It made the whole map go away.

Thank you so much, that did it.
Actually, it was much easier, as I'm building the data source URL myself, so just adding &zmax=20&zmin=1 to the URL sets the zoom levels.

Why has the question been closed as "off-topic"? Just trying to understand what is off/on topic. Isn't it addressing a problem that other people may encounter?

I agree with you that it might be interesting for other users. I think it was closed because you havnt provided any code example. If you update your question, it may be re-opened.

@DidacBusquets answered his/her own question:

The following code does set the maximum and minimum levels of the layer
(by appending it to the URL):
"type=xyz&url=http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a%7Bq%7D.jpeg?g=1&zmin=1&zmax=20"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, "Bing maps", "wms")


